# VS2005 Code Analysis: CA1063 (call dispose(true) and supress finalize) - with logging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, code-analysis, fxcop

I'm trying to adhere to the VS2005 code analysis rules for a new project.  I have this method:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dispose() called");
    Dispose( true );
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

*(The console call will become a log4net call at some point, and we're always interested in logging dispose for some of our types).*

The presense of the console debug line triggers this error:

*Error  1   CA1063 : Microsoft.Design : Modify PerfectDisposableClass.Dispose():Void so that it calls Dispose(true), then calls GC.SuppressFinalize on the current object instance ('this' or 'Me' in VB), and then returns.    F:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\DisposeAndFinalize\DisposeAndFinalize\PerfectDisposableClass.cs  26  DisposeAndFinalize*

Without resorting to pragma directives is there a way round this?  Perhaps writing my own rules?  Also, aer the existing rules in an assembly somewhere I can look at with reflector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the log statement inside the Dispose(bool disposing) method to keep within the guidelines:

```
public void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (disposing)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("...");
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Simple answers are always the best!  I had log calls in my Dispose(), Dispose( bool ) and finalizer.  No need for the log calles in Dispose() or the finalizer, I can just add them to Dispose( bool ) as you suggested, thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea when the Dispose(bool) method is a protected virtual? In that case I'd want the Console.WriteLine to be called before every disposal, then we'd still need the code to be what it is in the original post, and it would still break CA1063.